# 400 Bad Request From Javascript POST in .NET Web App

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am currently using .NET 7.0. And trying to send a JavaScript POST request when the quantity is changed on the browser which sends the following information:

[Image of paylaod information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OeWP.png)

But I am getting HTTP 400 Bad Request Errors.

Client.JS Post Request Code:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.btn-primary:not(.nav-btn)', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var barcode = $(this).attr("id");
        
        // Get quantities for both pallet and bag
        var palletQuantity = parseInt($(`#product-quantity-pallet-${barcode}`).text());
        var bagQuantity = parseInt($(`#product-quantity-bag-${barcode}`).text());


        $.ajax({
            url: "/Client/OnPostUpdateQuantity",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                barcode: barcode,
                palletQuantity: palletQuantity,
                bagQuantity: bagQuantity
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // Handle the successful response from the server
                console.log('Update quantity success:', response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle the error response from the server
                console.error('Update quantity error:', error);
            }
        });

        $(this).remove(); // Remove the button after successful submission
    });
```

And then the OnPostUpdateQuantity code is here which is stored inside the Client PageModel.

Please let me know if you require any more information

```
 [HttpPost]
 [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateQuantity(string barcode, int palletQuantity, int bagQuantity)
        {
            try
            {

                var product = await _context.Product.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Barcode == barcode);

                if (product != null)
                {
                    product.QuantityOfPallets = palletQuantity;
                    product.QuantityOfBag = bagQuantity;

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    
                    return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
                }
                else
                {
                   
                    return new JsonResult(new { success = false });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              
                return new JsonResult(new { success = false, responseText = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

I have tried to change the url to 'Client?handler=OnPostUpdateQuantity/' but this did not work.

But I believe that it cannot reach the URL correctly.

And I setup another method in the Client Page Model called test which will just return a true response.

```
[HttpPost]
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult test()
        {
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
```

And I used Postman API to try to get a response back but i get the same 400 bad request.

EDIT:
Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

// CORE ADMIN SETUP
builder.Services.AddCoreAdmin();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

// |------------------ CORE ADMIN SETUP ------------------|
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

// URL for core admin
app.UseCoreAdminCustomUrl("admin2");

// Title for panel
app.UseCoreAdminCustomTitle("TEST");

// |------------------ END CORE ADMIN SETUP ------------------|

app.Run();
```

EDIT 2
Client.cshtml.cs Code

```
namespace Project.Pages
{
    
    public class ClientModel : PageModel
    {
        private IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ClientModel(ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _context = context;
            _env = env;
        }

        public IList<Category> Category { get; set; } 


        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            // Get all categories with their products
            Category = await _context.Category.Include(c => c.Products).ToListAsync(); 
        }


       
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateQuantity(string barcode, int palletQuantity, int bagQuantity)
        {
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
}}
```

UPDATE I now just have two methods in the clinet.cshtml.cs which is the following:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult OnPostTest()
        {

            return Content("Success", "text/plain");
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetTest()
        {
            return Content("Success", "text/plain");
        }
```

I run this get request in postman https://localhost:44356/Client?handler=test and it works but when i try the same with the post i get 400 bad request

Update 2: Below is the updated program.cs and i created a blank page called test which is also below.

```
using Project.Database;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseStatusCodePages();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");


app.Run();
```

Test page .cshtml

```
@page
@model Project.Pages.TestModel
@{
}
```

.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Project.Pages
{
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {

        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult OnPostTest()
        {
            return Content("Success", "text/plain");
        }


        public IActionResult OnGetTest()
        {
            return Content("Success", "text/plain");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"And I used Postman API to try to get a response back but i get the same 400 bad request."* do you have any [action filter or middleware that runs before the controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) do? there is definitely something wrong on your asp.net code, but we cant tell as you provided a bunch of javascript **knowing** postman gets 400 too.

Comment: @BagusTesa Hi, I don't beleive I have any action filter or middleware tha runs before the controller. I can provide the full PageModel Code if you would like?

Comment: not even third party packages? check on your startup code (one with `app.UseRouting()` and bunch other lines).

Comment: could you create an empty GET controller action that just return HTTP 200 without json. see if anything changes. we had to narrow down the source of the problem bit-by-bit.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have updated the post to include Program.cs

Comment: Is it a blazor server app or razor app?

Comment: @BagusTesa I made a testGet() method and i was able to get a 200 request back from the postman

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I am unsure I believe i setup it up as a ASP.webapp

Comment: often the 400 response gives details on _what_ is wrong. Did you have a look at the response body?

Comment: looking at `builder.Services.AddCoreAdmin();` it seems you have third party package in your app and [it has filter](https://github.com/edandersen/core-admin/blob/master/src/DotNetEd.CoreAdmin/CoreAdminAuthFilter.cs). you might want to see if it the culprit of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

> I have made another edit and it works for a get request but when i try
> post it comes up with the 400 bad request error

Based on your comment I have simulated the test and got the exact output which is expected.On top of this, Based on my investigations, it seems that neither its your get or post method issue nor client page but your configuration. Most importantly, please check if you have any additional configuration which has not included within the question and that causing the error. In addition, you might check if there any subsequent condition for POST request.

Here is the steps and minimum configuration I had while testing the scnario...

ClientModel.cs file:

```
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public class ClientModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnPostTest()
        {

            return Content("Success", "text/plain");
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetTest()
        {
            return Content("Success", "text/plain");
        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

**Note:** Please, double check your program.cs configuration as I have seen few additional middleware and service there and I am guessing problem may arise from that. Be sure about the details.

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** As you can see, in my test everything is working accordingly. Hence, the takeway is, your configuration might causing your errors.

> I have tried to change the url to
> 'Client?handler=OnPostUpdateQuantity/' but this did not work. I used
> Postman API to try to get a response back but i get the same 400 bad
> request.

Based on your shared code snippet and from my inveestigation I have found two major mistakes.

First of all, your request route is not correct it should be  `url: "/YourPageName?handler=UpdateQuantity"`. You can check [how to write handler.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form)

Another crucial point is that,  your method is async which means the ajax request needs to know whether it is supposed to wait or can freely continue. So you need to use `async: false`.
async to false means the instructions following the ajax request will not run asynchronously, and thus will not execute any further code.

Let's have a look in practice. On how we can resolve it.

Project Type:

Please double check what kind of project you are working on. Here is the project I have reproduced the scenario on:

[image]

Method:

```
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public class Ajax400RequestModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateQuantity(string barcode, int palletQuantity, int bagQuantity)
        {
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
       
    }
```

**Note:** If you are using razor page, you don't need to use `[HttpPost]` because by default `OnPostUpdateQuantity` will be treated as `[HttpPost]`

Ajax Request Format:

```
           $.ajax({
                url: "/Ajax400Request?handler=UpdateQuantity",
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                method: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    barcode: 5,
                    palletQuantity: 10,
                    bagQuantity: 15
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    // Handle the successful response from the server
                    console.log('Update quantity success:', response);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle the error response from the server
                    console.error('Update quantity error:', error);
                }
            });
```

**Note:** To simulate your issue, I have modified your ajax request a bit and omitted unnecessary code snippet. In addition, my test page name is `Ajax400RequestModel` so my request route will be Ajax400Request as you can see in `url: "/Ajax400Request?handler=UpdateQuantity",`

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#the-home-page) in order to know more details.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, i have updated the URL but this doesn't seem to work as I already have a 'public async Task OnGetAsync()' method thats async for the categorys of the products. I have added an update above to show that full Client.cshtml.cs model code.

Comment: I have made another edit and it works for a get request but when i try post it comes up with the 400 bad request error. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your response @luke, I have investigated based on your comment and description and updated the answer along with the steps how I tested.

Comment: I have checked and my configuration looks pretty much the same as you. I tried to remove everything else and just have the get and post methods in the Page and it still doesn't work. Any idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: Also i made a brand new razer page and put in the get and post and the same issue occurs

Comment: Hows, your new project's program.cs files looks like and hows your PageModel's code snippet? I think, you should share that details, Its pretty obvious, something went wrong at your end, we need to figure out that.

Comment: I added an update 2

Comment: Okay, I will check and let you know the update,  to double check, what kind of application you are using? Blazor server or RazorPage App or MVC?

Comment: when I setup the project I selected "Blazer Server App Empty" I am unsure if this is correct or not. But thanks for all your help

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding @attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] at the top of the test.cshtml

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response, glad that your issue has been resolved. However, in my test both working accordingly.